# Can Jenkins update multiple Working copies(checked-out) of one Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a Subversion repository linked to Jenkins, and I have three checked-out instances of this repository on different IP addresses.(machines)

I am wondering if it is possible to 'update' all of those checked-out instances of that repository immediately and automatically, when there is a commit(change of code to the actual repository) from any of these repositories?

**change in CheckedOutRepo1 --> CheckedOutRepo2 automatically udpates**

Cheers

Comment: You will find an answer if you do research a little. :) I guess that you are looking for post-commit hook that will trigger Jenkins build.

Comment: If anyone has any specific information on the question I would be greatly appreciative, the information I have got regarding post commit hooks is in relation to creating a build , this is not my question above, my question is regarding updating working copies of the repository after a build or change has taken place.